# what is the value1 and value 2 in function of javascript for the sorting method

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

The following is the code:

```
 function compare(value1, value2){
      return (value1-value2); 
   };
   var values = [0, 1, 5, 10, 15];
   values.sort(compare);
   alert(values);
```

what is value1 and value2 in the code? Why when i return value1 - value2, it return the array item in ascending order but why when i return value2 - value1 in the function, it return array item in descending order?

Another question i would like to ask is why there is no any argument when compare function is defined in the sort method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function compare is called for each pair in the array. So in your case, compare would be called for 0 and 1, 1 and 5, 5 and 10, 10 and 15.

The arguments a represents the first item of the pair, and b represents the second item of the pair. In your example, compare would actually be called 4 times, once for each pair.

The reason compare isn't called inside .sort(compare) is because it is a delay call - it's not getting called right there, sort is calling it. So in this case `compare` is just the reference to the function.

Comment: Moreover, sort will check for the return value of compare calls for each pair. If the value is negative, then value1 is less than value2, if the result is 0 then the values are equal and if the result is a positive number than value1 is greater than value2. What you did was to implement ascending and descending sorting by playing with the sign of the result. Based on this results, sort() knows how to arrange items in the array to sort. This method can be and is used for any types of data (string, float or even more complex types - in this case it's your duty to correctly compare them).

Comment: @Adi Thanks, I did forget to mention that part of it.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm still wondering why there's no argument value defined in the compare function, what i'm meaning is values.sort(compare(argumentValue1, argumentValue2));

Comment: because sort has this builtin call. sort will always expect to comparte 2 values. you just pass to sort() the actual function to call and sort "hopes" the function will accept 2 params. try to pass to sort another function with no arguments defined at all and see what happens. I don't know what the result might be, maybe you get an exception or maybe sort will only look for the result

Comment: @dramasea because (I touched on it in my answer) is that compare isn't called instantly. It's passed into sort, and sort calls in.

Comment: @Chris This answer might touch on the truth, but it is still not quite right. The `compare` method is not called for each 'pair' (no such thing exist in an array) but is used to _compare_ any two items and return a value (-1,0,1) describing how one relates to the other (before, equal, after). How many times it's called depends entirely on the algorithm used to sort (bubble etc).

Comment: Pairs do in fact exist in arrays. As I stated this would be index 0 and index 1, then index 1 and index 2, and so forth. If you run a simple test you will quickly see sort will execute compare array.length - 1 times, one for each pair. I am happy to be corrected but please explain how compare is called by sort

Comment: @Chris - I think I did -  '.. any two items ..'. Which items (which index) and how many times is completely dependent on the sorting algorithm. And again, the _pairs_ you describe are not an intrinsic part of the `Array` data structure, it's just something you _regard_ as a pair. The only notion of _pair_ in an Array is the index/key and value.

Comment: @Sean I agree I do regard them as a pair, and are not an intrinsic part of the array data structure. But none the less, compare does take a 'pair' of elements

Comment: @Chris And the sun rise and fall. The notion of 'pair' has no place in this discussion as any item is part of n^2 pairs and so there is no point in distinguishing between them (ref the notion of pair vs 'any two item').

Comment: @Sean Ok Sean, I come to this site for mature conversations, condescending phrases such as 'And the sun rise and falls' is unneeded. I have already said I am happy to be corrected, but Mozilla refers to the items being passed in as 'pairs'. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort Quote:'when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments'

Comment: @Sean Again, this is for the sake of the community, the official ECMA standard as defined here http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf clearly states on page 139 specific pairs. Quote: 'Calling comparefn(a,b) always returns the same value v when given a specific pair of values a and b'

Comment: @Chris I'm quite familiar with the spec haven written js parsers and the notion of a 'pair' holds in the context of the `comparer`, but not when used in phrases such as '... each pair in the array...'. And not trying to be condescending, really, just trying to get through. Smile :)